# How to use git merge to ignore trailing whitespace?

Tags: git, merge

I'm expecting the following command to ignore changes to lines where by whitespace is either added or removed to the end of lines in the branch1 when it merges that content into the current branch:

```
git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol --no-commit --no-ff branch1
```

But the following script, when executed, demonstrates that the lines, that have changes to trailing whitespace, are still added.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Transcribe all commands:
set -x

# Show the version I'm using:
git --version

# Create the repo and add a initial file:
cd /tmp
rm -rf scrap
mkdir scrap
cd scrap
git init
echo "// line 1 " > sample.C
echo "// line 2" >> sample.C
git add sample.C
git diff --cached | sed 's% $%EOLWS%g'
git commit -m "change 1"

# Create a new branch and add changes to it:
git checkout -b branch1
# Change an existing line by changing the whitespace at the end of one line:
sed -i 's%// line 1 %// line 1%g' sample.C
git add sample.C
# Check the whitespace was changed prior to committing:
git diff --cached | sed 's% $%EOLWS%g'
git commit -m "Add trailing whitespace"

# Check out master and merge into it, expecting no lines containing only trailing whitespace to be included:
git checkout master
git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol --no-commit --no-ff branch1
git diff --cached | sed 's% $%EOLWS%g'
```

The above results in the following output. I've added line numbers for referencing later:

```
     1  + git --version
     2  git version 2.20.1
     3  + cd /tmp
     4  + rm -rf scrap
     5  + mkdir scrap
     6  + cd scrap
     7  + git init
     8  Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/scrap/.git/
     9  + echo '// line 1 '
    10  + echo '// line 2'
    11  + git add sample.C
    12  + git diff --cached
    13  + sed 's% $%EOLWS%g'
    14  diff --git a/sample.C b/sample.C
    15  new file mode 100644
    16  index 0000000..42b5bc0
    17  --- /dev/null
    18  +++ b/sample.C
    19  @@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
    20  +// line 1EOLWS
    21  +// line 2
    22  + git commit -m 'change 1'
    23  [master (root-commit) 07cd37f] change 1
    24   1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
    25   create mode 100644 sample.C
    26  + git checkout -b branch1
    27  Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
    28  + sed -i 's%// line 1 %// line 1%g' sample.C
    29  + git add sample.C
    30  + git diff --cached
    31  + sed 's% $%EOLWS%g'
    32  diff --git a/sample.C b/sample.C
    33  index 42b5bc0..4b9e635 100644
    34  --- a/sample.C
    35  +++ b/sample.C
    36  @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
    37  -// line 1EOLWS
    38  +// line 1
    39   // line 2
    40  + git commit -m 'Add trailing whitespace'
    41  [branch1 6144b0c] Add trailing whitespace
    42   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
    43  + git checkout master
    44  Switched to branch 'master'
    45  + git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol --no-commit --no-ff branch1
    46  Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
    47  + git diff --cached
    48  + sed 's% $%EOLWS%g'
    49  diff --git a/sample.C b/sample.C
    50  index 42b5bc0..4b9e635 100644
    51  --- a/sample.C
    52  +++ b/sample.C
    53  @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
    54  -// line 1EOLWS
    55  +// line 1
    56   // line 2
```

The "EOLWS" word is expected on lines 20 and 37, but not on 54.

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what the idea behind "ignore-space-at-eol" is (of course, otherwise you wouldn't be asking :)).

[`ignore-space-at-eol`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ignore-space-at-eol) is a merge strategy option for the [`recursive` merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-recursive). These options only apply to *conflicts* (this is the important bit!)

The MWE you provided is creating a branch with additional commits not on master, but master does not have any other commits (so in theory it could be fast-forwarded, but since `--no-ff` is passed, that's not happening).

So, in this case, a normal merge is being made. All changes not in master but only on the branch are merged into master. Since there are no conflicts, the `-Xignore-space-at-eol` does not take effect.

It would take effect, if you had eol-whitespace-only-changes in both branches to the same line and then try to merge it, i.e.:

```
$ git init
$ >file echo 'a'
$ git add file
$ git commit -m 'initial'
$ git branch feature # create a branch, but do not switch to it
$ >file echo 'a ' # add one blank
$ git add file ; git commit -m 'add one blank on master'
$ git checkout feature
$ >file echo 'a  ' # add two blank
$ git add file ; git commit -m 'add two blanks branch'
$ git checkout master ; git merge feature # you will get conflicts
$ git merge --abort # let's try that again:
$ git merge -Xignore-space-at-eol feature # no conflicts, hooray!
```

You see, `ignore-space-at-eol` is a strategy option how to handle conflicts. It does not mean that such changes will be ignored completely.

Use case: you want to merge a branch which does not match line endings or whitespace of your branch (think CRLF vs LF). With this strategy option you can automatically resolve such conflicts and cleanly merge the changes.